# Why does this FOR Loop count 0 rows with one row passed in but counts 2 after adding a second row?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

For some reason, len (data.length) is 0 when there is only one row and jumps to 2 as soon as I add a row.  I've checked to see if the function is counting one row above or below my intended range and it is not.  It counts the right amount of 'Externals' as long as I have more than one row.  I am unsure of why this may be.

```
//Get data.length of range passed in  through argument
//loop through the range based on number of rows and count 'External'
function count_external(data)
{
  var len = data.length;
  var total_external = 0;

  var i = 0;

  for(i = 0; i < len;i++)
  {
   if(!data[i][0])
   {
     total_external += 1;
   }
  }

  return total_external;
}
```

Comment: The function itself seems fine. Have you tried to output the data that is passed in in both cases?

Answer (score 1):

- If `data.length` returns `0`, then `data` is an empty string.
- If `data` is an empty string, then the statement `total_external +=1;` is not executed because `data.lenght` is `0` and the `for` condition is `i < 0`